# set image color of a template image

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, nsimageview

I have an image like this:
[image]

(Rendered as a template image)

I tried this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgAdd: NSImageView!
imgAdd.layer?.backgroundColor = CGColor.white
```

Which only changes the background color of course.

Is there a way to change the color of this image programmatically?

---

So far I've tried the code below which doesn't work. (The image color doesn't change.)

```
func tintedImage(_ image: NSImage, tint: NSColor) -> NSImage {
    guard let tinted = image.copy() as? NSImage else { return image }
    tinted.lockFocus()
    tint.set()

    let imageRect = NSRect(origin: NSZeroPoint, size: image.size)
    NSRectFillUsingOperation(imageRect, .sourceAtop)

    tinted.unlockFocus()
    return tinted
}

imgDok.image = tintedImage(NSImage(named: "myImage")!, tint: NSColor.red)
```

Comment: they are talking about NSImages. I need a solution for NSImageView

Comment: i updated my first post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution with everyone's help:

**(Swift 3)**

```
func tintedImage(_ image: NSImage, tint: NSColor) -> NSImage {
    guard let tinted = image.copy() as? NSImage else { return image }
    tinted.lockFocus()
    tint.set()

    let imageRect = NSRect(origin: NSZeroPoint, size: image.size)
    NSRectFillUsingOperation(imageRect, .sourceAtop)

    tinted.unlockFocus()
    return tinted
}

imgDok.image = tintedImage(NSImage(named: "myImage")!, tint: NSColor.red)
```

**Important:** in interface builder I had to set the *"render as"* setting of the image to *"Default"*.

Comment: please consider updating the answer to this question, so that the Swift 5 answer is marked as correct

Answer (score 16):

#### Swift 4

Updated answer for Swift 4

Please note, this `NSImage` extension is based on *@Ghost108* and *@Taehyung_Cho's* answers, so a larger credit goes to them.

```
extension NSImage {
    func tint(color: NSColor) -> NSImage {
        let image = self.copy() as! NSImage
        image.lockFocus()

        color.set()

        let imageRect = NSRect(origin: NSZeroPoint, size: image.size)
        imageRect.fill(using: .sourceAtop)

        image.unlockFocus()

        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: Why must the image _not_ be a template? I figured it _should_ be?

Comment: it works fine for me. I inverted the logic so that this _only_ applies the tint to template images, and all's good; now my template images behave as they should when custom-drawn: black on light backgrounds and white on dark ones.

Comment: That's good to know. If that's the case, there need be no conditional logic at all, since both template and regular images can be tinted.

Comment: All answers here using `image.lockFocus()` suffer from the same issues: they're not playing well with retina images on retina display (they draw at 1x) and don't play well with dynamic colors. Prefer the `NSImage` block-based drawing initializer instead, like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64049177/400056).

Comment: Note the swift version and date of the answers.  Unless you have something useful to add, concentrate only on newer answers, or add your own if it's missing.  No one should look to answers that were posted about Swift 4 in 2018.

Comment: @DarkDust btw, you have the ability to make the changes I just did, also that hat.  Chef's kiss.

Comment: The [API I'm referring to is available since macOS 10.8](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1519860-init), that is 2012. Your answer isn't _wrong_ , but since it's the top answer I felt it's a good idea to point out issues with this approach that can be avoided.

Answer (score 13):

## Swift 5

This method should be used: (note the other answers, using `NSImage.lockFocus()` is deprecated macOS 10.0–13.0)

```swift
extension NSImage {
    func tint(color: NSColor) -> NSImage {
        NSImage(size: size, flipped: false) { rect in
            color.set()
            rect.fill()
            self.draw(in: rect, from: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: self.size), operation: .destinationIn, fraction: 1.0)
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Note: When using `.withAlphaComponent(0.5)` on an `NSColor` instance, that color loses support for switching between light/dark mode. It's recommend to use color assets, to avoid the issue.

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct way now that lockFocus is deprecated.

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4 version**

```
extension NSImage {
   func image(withTintColor tintColor: NSColor) -> NSImage {
       guard isTemplate else { return self }
       guard let copiedImage = self.copy() as? NSImage else { return self }
       copiedImage.lockFocus()
       tintColor.set()
       let imageBounds = NSMakeRect(0, 0, copiedImage.size.width, copiedImage.size.height)
       imageBounds.fill(using: .sourceAtop)
       copiedImage.unlockFocus()
       copiedImage.isTemplate = false
       return copiedImage
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Since your image is inside an NSImageView, the following should work fine (available since macOS 10.14):

```
let image = NSImage(named: "myImage")!
image.isTemplate = true
let imageView = NSImageView(image: image)
imageView.contentTintColor = .green
```

The solution is to apply "contentTintColor" to your NSImageView instead of the NSImage.

See: [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimageview/3000783-contenttintcolor)

Answer (score 6):

Had to modify @Ghost108's answer little bit for Xcode 9.2.

```
NSRectFillUsingOperation(imageRect, .sourceAtop)
```

to

```
imageRect.fill(using: .sourceAtop)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Props for crediting the answer you are improving--but you should include enough surrounding code so that your answer stands on its own without needing to reference the other.

Comment: TBH this should be an edit to the accepted answer, not an entire other answer unto itself

Comment: @BenLeggiero The queue of suggestions is full, he is unable to edit.

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1):

no need to copt:
extension NSImage {

```
func tint(with color: NSColor) -> NSImage {
    self.lockFocus()
    color.set()
    let srcSpacePortionRect = NSRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: self.size)
    srcSpacePortionRect.fill(using: .sourceAtop)
    self.unlockFocus()
    return self
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use the UIImage functions, you can try using CoreImage (CI). I don't know if there is an easier version but this one will work fore sure!

First you create the CIImage

```
    let image = CIImage(data: inputImage.tiffRepresentation!)
```

Now you can apply all kinds of filters and other stuff to the image, it's a really powerful tool.

The documentation for CI: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage

The Filter List: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html

Here is a simple filter example, you basically initialise a filter and then set the values for it, output it and repeat.

```
    let yourFilterName = CIFilter(name: "FilterName")
    yourFilterName!.setValue(SomeInputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    yourFilterName!.setValue(10, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
    let yourFilterName = yourFilterName!.outputImage
```

Now you can just convert the output back as NSImage.

```
    let cgimg = context.createCGImage(yourFilterName!, from: yourFilterName!.extent)
    let processedImage = NSImage(cgImage: cgimg!, size: NSSize(width: 0, height: 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5 and SF Symbols 4.0

You can access to the full system icons api using `SymbolConfiguration` as this:

```swift
if var image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "rainbow", accessibilityDescription: nil) {
    var config = NSImage.SymbolConfiguration(textStyle: .body, scale: .large)
    config = config.applying(.preferringMulticolor())
        //.applying(.init(hierarchicalColor: .green))
        //.applying(.init(paletteColors: [.blue, .blue, .green, .white, .systemTeal, .systemPink]))
    quitMenuItem.image = image.withSymbolConfiguration(config)
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Try this code it helps.

**Swift 3**

```
let theImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"foo")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate))
theImageView.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: sry but i need a OS X / cocoa solution. not iOS :(